# ¿Si desinstalo pgAdmin se queda instalado PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin

Quiero desinstalar PgAdmin4 pero no sé si eso hará que se desinstale PostgreSQL o si afecta a mis bases de datos que tengo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Si desinstalas PgAdmin4, no sucede nada con PostgreSQL. Por que PGAdmin es "es una aplicación gráfica para gestionar el gestor de bases de datos PostgreSQL"

Si quieres una buena aplicación para gestionar bd, te recomiendo dbeaver
http://dbeaver.jkiss.org/